# WCF Serialization -More Information

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

I read some microsoft articles.They explained that WCF uses `DataContractSerializer` for serialization.But the articles did not explain why DataContractSerializer preferred over 
XmlSerialization.Can anyone give me the additional information?

Comment: Here's another really good article in MSDN Magazine, on [WCF Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) is an article with a comparison.

Key section:

### XmlSerializer

Advantages:

1. Opt-out rather than opt-in properties to serialize. This mean you don’t have to specify each and every property to serialize, only those you don’t wan to serialize2. Full control over how a property is serialized including it it should be a node or an attribute
2. Supports more of the XSD standard

Disadvantages:

1. Can only serialize properties
2. Properties must be public
3. Properties must have a get and a set which can result in some awkward design
4. Supports a narrower set of types
5. Cannot understand the DataContractAttribute and will not serialize it unless there is a SerializableAttribute too

### DataContractSerializer

Advantages:

1. Opt-in rather than opt-out properties to serialize. This mean you specify what you want serialize
2. Because it is opt in you can serialize not only properties, but also fields.  You can even serialize non-public members such as private or protected members. And you dont need a set on a property either (however without a setter you can serialize, but not deserialize)
3. Is about 10% faster than XmlSerializer to serialize the data because since you don’t have full control over how it is serialize, there is a lot that can be done to optimize the serialization/deserialization process.
4. Can understand the SerializableAttribute and know that it needs to be serialized
5. More options and control over KnownTypes

Disadvantages:

1. No control over how the object is serialized outside of setting the name and the order